# runtime error: null pointer passed as argument 1, which is declared to never be null

Tags: c, pointers, cs50

I wrote a program that creates Linkedlists with two values.
It worked when I just had int values in it but now that I added char* this error messages shows
runtime error: null pointer passed as argument 1, which is declared to never be null

As mentioned before this worked fine until I added char* to the constructor and the struct. Not sure where it goes wrong as the error seems to come from different lines in the code everytime I run it... So what do i need to change ?

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <cs50.h>
   #include <string.h>

typedef struct node  {
        int val;
        char* name;
        struct node *next;
} node_t;

void addFirst(int value, char* word, node_t** nd) {
        //initialize new node, allocate space, set value
    node_t * tmp;
    tmp = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    tmp->val = value;
    strcpy(tmp->name, word);
    //let the new nodes next pointer point to the old head
    tmp->next = *nd;
    //Make tmp the head node
    *nd = tmp;



}


int findItem(int value,char* word, node_t *nd) {
    if(nd->val == value)
    return 0;
    while(nd->next != NULL) {
    if(nd->val == value && strcmp(word, nd->name) == 0)
    return 0;

    if(nd->next != NULL)
    nd = nd->next;
    }
    return -1;

}


int main (void) {

 node_t *head = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
 head->val = 0;
  strcpy(head->name, "");
    head->next = NULL;
    addFirst(15, "word", &head);
    addFirst(14,"word2", &head);


    printf("%i \n", findItem(15, "word", head));

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `strcpy(head->name, "");`. Here, you;re trying to use the memory location pointer to by `head->name`, but you never assigned a valid memory to it.

You need to make sure that the pointer points to a valid memory location, before you write to / read from that memory location. Attempt to access invalid memory invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

This is applicable for other uninitialized instances of `name`, too.

If you can live with POSIX standard, instead of `strcpy()`, you can make use of [`strdup()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup)

Comment: The same for `strcpy(tmp->name, word);` in `addFirst()`.

Comment: @DevSolar indeed,

Comment: `tmp->name = strdup(word);` instead of `strcpy(tmp->name, word);` and similar for `""` would help.

Comment: @Bodo: I am always of two minds about whether to mention `strdup()` or not. Yes, it is a useful shortcut. But it is *not* part of the language standard. (And it is a function that allocates memory you have to call `free()` on, that is *not* named `*alloc()`.)